# py2neo exists return wrong result

Tags: python, neo4j, exists, py2neo

when i use py2neo  exists() 
i get a wrong result,i think the result will be 'True',but it give a 'False'
when i use

```
c = Node("Person", name="Alice")
g.exists(c)
```

it return a 'False',
but when i change like this

```
c = a
g.exists(c)
```

i will get a 'True'
why?

```
from py2neo import Graph,Node,Relationship
g = py2neo.Graph('http://localhost:7474', user='yudeng',password='yudeng')
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
print(a)
g.create(a)
g.create(b)
g.create(ab)
c = Node("Person", name="Alice")
g.exists(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just state

```
c = Node("Person", name="Alice")
g.exists(c)
```

Result:

```
False
```

without

```
g.create(c)
```

Then the node does not exist because you did not created the node in the graph.

This is what you executed to get a True:

```
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
print(a)
g.create(a)
g.create(b)
g.create(ab)
c = a
g.exists(c)
```

Because then c equals to a that means the node exists => Node("Person", name="Alice") can then be found with a and c.

Result:

```
(:Person {name: 'Alice'})

True
```